# Attempt to de-reference a null object on Map

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

I'm building a method to update two date fields when a different date field is edited. When I update one of the date fields or both of the fields the error in the debug log is "Attempt to de-reference a null object".

My method looks like this:

```
private void updateRenewalDates(Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap)
{
    // Create Lists to hold data
    List<OpportunityLineItem> renewals = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>> oppToLineItem = new Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>>();

    // Loop through filter records from the api call and see if they meet the criteria
    System.debug('list of renewals is: ' + renewals); // Should be blank
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should be blank
    System.debug('newMap is ' + newMap); // Should have a value
    System.debug('oldMap is ' + oldMap); // Should have a vlaue

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli:newMap.values())
    {
        if((oli.Start_Date__c != oldMap.get(oli.id).Start_Date__c) || (oli.End_Date__c != oldMap.get(oli.id).End_Date__c))
        {
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should be blank        
            oppToLineItem.get(oli.Id).add(oli);
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should not blank       
        }
    }

    // Get the record fields for records where the id is from our list
    renewals = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, Start_Date_Renewal__c, End_Date__c, End_Date_Renewal__c, Opportunity.ContractTerm__c 
                FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                WHERE Id in:oppToLineItem.keyset()];

    // Loop through results of the query and update the record with the new value       
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem:renewals)
    {
        List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = oppToLineItem.get(oppLineItem.OpportunityId);
        for(OpportunityLineItem line:olis)
        {
    // Update Renewal dates with the start/end date + Contract length       
            line.Start_Date_Renewal__c = line.Start_Date__c.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(line.Opportunity.ContractTerm__c));
            line.End_Date_Renewal__c = line.End_Date__c.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(line.Opportunity.ContractTerm__c));
        }
    }

}
```

More specifically I think the error is in this chunk:

```
 for(OpportunityLineItem oli:newMap.values())
    {
        if((oli.Start_Date__c != oldMap.get(oli.id).Start_Date__c) || (oli.End_Date__c != oldMap.get(oli.id).End_Date__c))
        {
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should be blank        
            oppToLineItem.get(oli.Id).add(oli);
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should not blank       
        }
    }
```

In my debug log it shows that the map oppToLineItem is null, hence the de-reference a null object. However, I can also see the newMap and oldMap and the value is different as I expect in my criteria. How come then the record does not get added to the Map if it does meet the criteria?

Comment: What's the line number in that error message that it is logging? And where is that specific line in the code you posted above?

Comment: the line is 139 which is the oppToLineItem.get(oli.Id).add(oli);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing two things at once: filtering and grouping. The grouping is where you're going astray.

Here's what you are doing in a more expanded format.

```
Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> byParent = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
for (OpportunityLineItem item : trigger.new)
{
    if (/*condition*/)
    {
        List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = byParent.get(item.Id);
        // lineItems is null because you never put anything in the map
        // so of course you can't add anything to it yet

        lineItems.add(item); // will throw NPE
    }
}
```

Here's how the grouping part *should* look.

```
Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> byParent = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
for (OpportunityLineItem item : trigger.new)
{
    if (!byParent.contains(item.OpportunityId))
        byParent.put(item.OpportunityId, new List<OpportunityLineItem>());
    List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = byParent.get(item.OpportunityId);
    // now you've put something in the map
    // you always know this list will be non-null

    lineItems.add(item); // will not throw NPE
}
```

The filtering would be best done separately:

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for (OpportunityLineItem item : trigger.new)
{
    if (/*condition*/) dateRangeChanged.add(item);
}
```

You can make this functionality more reusable by moving it into separate, `static` methods.

```
public static void List<OpportunityLineItem> hasDateRangeChanged
    (List<OpportunityLineItem> newRecords, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap)
{
    // implementation
}
public static void Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> groupByParent
    (List<OpportunityLineItem> items)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Then in your trigger, you can just do:

```
Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> byParent = OliService.groupByParent(
    OliService.hasDateRangeChanged(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap)
);
```

Comment: What? you lost me.

Comment: We can also [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44077/grouping-npe) if you're still lost.

Comment: can we chat about this?

Answer (score 2):

Adrian's answer is a great solution.

Here's another approach, which will specifically fix the null pointer exception that's being thrown. I didn't look into the logic of your implementation to spot any issues with it.

Your code assumes that there's a list already in the map tied to the key, but you never instantiated a list to be in the map - you've only defined the map itself.

```
if (criteria) {
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should be blank        
    // this line assumes that there is already a list<> in this map when
    // you are calling .add()
    oppToLineItem.get(oli.Id).add(oli);
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should not blank
}
```

A basic solution would be to check for `null` before calling `.add()` and if it's `null`, initialize the list in the map at that point.

```
if (criteria) {
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should be blank        
    List<OpportunityLineItem> items = oppToLineItem.get(oli.Id);

    // check to see if the list exists already
    if (items == null) {

        // initialize a new list and add the current item to it during construction of the list
        oppToLineItem.put(oli.OpportunityId, new List<OpportunityLineItem>{oli});
    } else {

        // get the existing list and add the item to it
        oppToLineItem.get(oli.id).add(oli);
    }
    System.debug('Map of oppToLineItem is ' + oppToLineItem); // Should not blank
}
```

Comment: Also the map's keys should be the `OpportunityId` rather than the line item id for proper operation. I'm leaving the example above as-is, but this is pretty important. :-)

Comment: Hmm I just noticed you actually don't use a key at all! You do `Map.put(List)`. This strategy was how I started grouping, I switched over after some time reading others' code.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for catching the syntax error on the `Map.put()`, unfortunately it won't automagically pull out the key from the sobject's id field using that syntax and my previous implementation wouldn't actually compile.